# error while loading shared libraries: libpulsecommon-13.99.so

Tags: 18.04, pulseaudio, kdenlive

I am trying to open Kdenlive for the UI, but nothing happned.
So I tried from the terminal and get this error.

> /snap/kdenlive/45/usr/bin/kdenlive: error while loading shared
> libraries: libpulsecommon-13.99.so: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.6

Comment: Remove problematic Snap and use other alternatives.